# How to change VirtualizingStackPanel Margin for portrait mode?

Tags: winrt-xaml

I have the following GridView

```
<GridView
        x:Name="itemGridView"
        AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemGridView"
        AutomationProperties.Name="Grouped Items"
        Grid.RowSpan="2"
        Margin="0,-14,0,0"
        Padding="0,0,0,50"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource groupedItemsViewSource}}"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Standard250x250ItemTemplate}"
        SelectionMode="None"
        IsSwipeEnabled="false"
        IsItemClickEnabled="True"
        ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick">

        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>                        
                 <VirtualizingStackPanel x:Name="ItemGridViewVirtualizingStackPanel" Margin="120,0,120,0" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
...
```

In `<VisualState x:Name="FullScreenPortrait">` I try to change the Margin

```
<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ItemGridViewVirtualizingStackPanel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin">
    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="100,0,20,0"/>
</ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

But Error appears `Cannot resolve TargetName ItemGridViewVirtualizingStackPanel.`

So how to change Margin of VirtualizingStackPanel?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reference controls created from an `ItemTemplate` in the `StoryBoard`, because the name you used is the name of the *ItemTemplate*, and not the control(s) *generated from* the template.

In this situation I would either react to the orientation change in the **code behind** and change the margin of the controls by hand in C#, or I would **bind** the `Margin` of the `VirtualizingStackPanel` to a property of your **view model**, and update that property accordingly when the orientation changes.

The solution you choose might depend on that how much knowledge of the presentation you'd like to put in your view model.

Comment: Thank, you! For now, I've added GridView x:Name="itemGridViewPortrait" with the valid layout

Comment: That's maybe the simplest solution, but it's not optimal performance-wise, because this way your Visual Tree will be two times larger at runtime.